# Trying to find the regex for this particular case? Also can I parse this without creating groups?

Tags: python, regex

text to capture looks like this..

```
  Policy Number    ABCD000012345    other text follows in same line....
```

My regex looks like this

```
 regex value='(?i)(?:[P|p]olicy\s[N|n]o[|:|;|,][\n\r\s\t]*[\na-z\sA-Z:,;\r\d\t]*[S|s]e\s*[H|h]abla\s*[^\n]*[\n\s\r\t]*|(?i)[P|p]olicy[\s\n\t\r]*[N|n]umber[\s\n\r\t]*)(?P&lt;policy_number&gt;[^\n]*)'
```

this particular case matches with the second or case.. however it is also capturing everything after the policy number. What can be the stopping condition for it to just grab the number. I know something is wrong but can't find a way out.

```
 (?i)[P|p]olicy[\s\n\t\r]*[N|n]umber[\s\n\r\t]*)
```

current output

```
    ABCD000012345othertextfollowsinsameline....
```

expected output

```
   ABCD000012345
```

Comment: There is always two words before ? What is the expected structure of the ID to retrieve is there any specific format ?

Comment: the id can be a mix of alphabets and numeric or either or. that's the only condition so as long as it grabs the content between two spaces

Comment: 1. Is there a fixed number of words before ? Does the ID is letter then digits of mixed in every way ? Could you provide more example of inputs to validate ?

Comment: `[P|p]` matches either `P`, `|`, or `p`. Adding `(?i)` makes it match any case, so `[Pp]` isn't needed. Your regex is way over-complicated. Maybe just match on `^.*?(?: {4}|\t)(\S+)` - results in first group? Tough to say cause you haven't actually given us any rules to abide by (regex is literally just rules - so not having any makes it extremely difficult to guess your situation)

Comment: you are right about the casing actually. will get rid of it. All the text is supposed to look like this for the stuff i am working on now. My only aim is to grab everything between the first space and the second space where the id actually is. The id can be a string of any format and i still need to capture it. I am not trying to get a validation for the id as i directly store whatever is captured in the database.

Comment: @tm_2906 I assume the ID never contains a space? I'm also assuming a string can start with something other than `policy number`? Is the "first space" that you mention a tab or 4 spaces?

Comment: any number of spaces. anything between 1 to 5 o 6 spaces. the id doe not contain spaces

Comment: `^policy number\s+(\S+)`

Comment: thank you for all your help and patience. I finally have the code working after spending a day and a half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a more simple regex, just finding from the beginning `"[P|p]olicy\s*[N|n]umber\s*\b([A-Z]{4}\d+)\b.*"` and use the word boundary `\b`

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[P|p]olicy\s*[N|n]umber\s*\b([A-Z0-9]+)\b.*")
line = "Policy Number    ABCD000012345    other text follows in same line...."
matches = pattern.match(line)
id_res = matches.group(1)
print(id_res)  # ABCD000012345
```

And if there's always 2 words before you can use `(?:\w+\s+){2}\b([A-Z0-9]+)\b.*`

---

Also `\s` is for `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` so no need to repeat them, your `[\n\r\s\t]` is just `\s`

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the upper and lower case `p` and `n` specified since you're already specifying case insensitive.

Also `\s` already covers `\n`, `\t` and `\r`.

```
(?i)policy\s+number\s+([A-Z]{4}\d+)\b
```

for verification purpose: [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Lhpmda/2)

Another Solution:

```
^[\s\w]+\b([A-Z]{4}\d+)\b
```

for verification purpose: [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Lhpmda/3)

I like this better, in case your text changes from policy number