# finding a regex to match and also trying to avoid using groups

Tags: python, regex

```
Policy Id NPOH123414699 xyz OH 12605-12345 NASHVILLE TN 37101
Policy Id 9214234451
Policy Id AS12345FD ..... other info
```

I am trying to grab the number right after Id and only that and stop as soon as a space is encountered after the id. I don't know how to it.

```
my regex -->> "[P|p]olicy\s*[I|i]d\s*"
```

However it is capturing everything after Policy number and giving me this

```
 NPOH123414699xyzOH1260512345NASHVILLETN37101
```

Comment: Why don't you just String.Split() over space and take the third item in the resulting array?

Comment: Personally, I absolutely love the title, but you really should check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you make proper ones.

Comment: `^Policy Id (\S+)` <- result in capture group 1

Comment: because I am trying to use regex to make it more generic as I mentioned the format might vary every time. sometimes, the line would end right there and sometimes there could be more stuff in the same sentence I would want to skip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to find the regex for this particular case? Also can I parse this without creating groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58921797/trying-to-find-the-regex-for-this-particular-case-also-can-i-parse-this-without)

Comment: yup, still haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: The pattern that you use `[P|p]olicy\s*[N|n]umber\s*` does not match any of the example data. What do you want to match exactly? If you want to match the number only after the Id, perhaps you could use `\bPolicy Id \D*(\d+)` See https://regex101.com/r/hdL8BQ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex without groups only full matches that u need to iterate `(?<=Policy Id\s)\w+`

here it is: https://regex101.com/r/8GEDs1/1

Answer (score 1):

You can:
(?<=\bPolicy Id\s)(\w+)

Reference:
https://regex101.com/r/LrzDX5/1

Answer (score 1):

this simple pattern should be more than enough if you insist to use regex

```
a = re.findall(r"Id\s([0-9A-Z]+)", "Policy Id B1231232131 xysa da")[0]
```